# Why won't the click listener log the user clicking on the div for the first time but does log every other time?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

**Background information:** I'm dealing with many `div`s and recording the `data-id` of the particular `div` that user has clicked on.

I'm not sure why the click listener doesn't log the very first time I click on a div but it does log every other time.

For example, if I navigate to the page and click on a `div`, the `data-id` doesn't get logged at all.

But when I click on another `div`, it does get logged. If I keep clicking on another `div`, it does get logged, and so on.

How can I fix it so that whenever I navigate to the page for the first time and click on a `div`, the data gets logged?

Here's my JS code:

```
let img = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

let userClicked = function () {
    let attribute = this.getAttribute("data-id");
    console.log("clicked " + attribute);
}

for(let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].addEventListener('click', userClicked, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my view problem is somewhere else. Try checking if any other element overlaps or your JS is loading at right time. You can check sample code here. Paste it in separate html file and it will work perfectly file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Image</title>
    <style>
        div {
            background-color:#eaeaea;
            margin-bottom:5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-id="1" class="item">1 </div>
    <div data-id="2" class="item">2 </div>
    <div data-id="3" class="item">3 </div>
    <div data-id="4" class="item">4 </div>
    <script>
        let img = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
        let userClicked = function () {
            let attribute = this.getAttribute("data-id");
            console.log("clicked " + attribute);
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
            img[i].addEventListener('click', userClicked, false);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah you might be right, I was just thinking that actually. Thanks for your input.

Comment: If you can post your complete html it will be helpful to find problem